# Status code error while posting json data using google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I was writing an app script to send an sms. In the sms api document section, it's written that with the following, sms can be sent:

```
POST http://clients.muthofun.net/api/v3/sendsms/json 
Host: http://clients.muthofun.net 
Content-Type: application/json 
Accept: */*

{
   "authentication":{
      "username":"test",
      "password":"test"
   },
   "messages":[
      {
         "sender":"044XXXXXXXX",
         "text":"Hello",
         "recipients":[
            {
               "gsm":"88017XXXXXXXX"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

So I write the following script code,
**modified as @Tanaike said**

```
function myFunction() {

    var _auth = {
      "username": "*****", 
      "password": "*****"
    };

    var rec = {
      "gsm": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    };


    var msg = {
      "sender": "xxxxxxxxxxx", 
      "text": "Hello", 
      "recipients": [rec]
    };

    var payload = {
      "authentication": _auth,
      "messages": [msg]
    };

    _payload = JSON.stringify(payload)


    var options = {
      'method' : 'POST',
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      "accept": "*/*",
      "payload": _payload
    };

    var url = "http://clients.muthofun.net/api/v3/sendsms/json";

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

    Logger.log(response);
}
```

But the actual response is:

```
{  
   "results":[  
      {  
         "status":"0",
         "messageid":"10210011344550330860",
         "destination":"88017XXXXXXXX"
      }
   ]
}
```

but from the `Logger` function I get the following response

```
{  
   "results":[  
      {  
         "status":"-5",
         "messageid":"",
         "destination":"8801552555645"
      }
   ]
}
```

Is it because I missed out a square bracket in the recipients and messages section? Or I am doing something wrong while sending the post request to the url?

Comment: I'm really sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: It's ok. You helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about this modification? In your sample request body, `messages` is as follows.

```
{
  "authentication": {
    "username": "test",
    "password": "test"
  },
  "messages": [
    {
      "sender": "044XXXXXXXX",
      "text": "Hello",
      "recipients": [
        {
          "gsm": "88017XXXXXXXX"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In your script, it is as follows.

```
{
  "authentication": {
    "username": "*****",
    "password": "*****"
  },
  "messages": {
    "sender": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "text": "Hello",
    "recipients": {
      "gsm": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  }
}
```

In your script, the values of `messages` and `recipients` are not array. So how about this modification?

#### Modified script :

From :

```
var msg = {
  "sender": "xxxxxxxxxxx", 
  "text": "Hello", 
  "recipients": rec
};

var payload = {
  "authentication": _auth,
  "messages": msg
};
```

To :

```
var msg = {
  "sender": "xxxxxxxxxxx", 
  "text": "Hello", 
  "recipients": [rec] // Modified
};

var payload = {
  "authentication": _auth,
  "messages": [msg] // Modified
};
```

And `accept` should be included in headers.

I'm not sure whether this modification resolves your issue, because I cannot test it. If this was not useful for you, can you provide the detail situation of the error?

### Edit :

In this modification, `option` was modified.

```
var options = {
  "method" : "POST",
  "contentType": "application/json",
  "headers": {"accept": "*/*"}, // Modified
  "payload": payload // Modified
};
```

Comment: I used your modified version. Though now, the payload looks like the json given in the doc, getting the same error,
`{"results": [
{"status":"-5","messageid":"","destination":"8801552555645"}
]}`

From the doc, what I found is, if the status code is -13 then the phone number formation is wrong, if it's -1 then username/password is wrong. For something else, something wrong has happened!

Comment: @sphoenix I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. From your question and comment, I'm not sure about the detail of document for the API and each value for your private information. But it is found that the modified request body is the same with the sample request body in your question. Can you provide the detail information of document and your latest script? If you can do, can you add them to your question by editing your question?

Comment: @sphoenix Thank you for your response. If the document of API is from [here](http://www.muthofun.com/index.php/muthofun-developer-api/), I could confim about it. And in my answer, I said that "``accept`` should be included in headers.". So please put it to the header. But I think that this might not be the direct solution of your issue. Because the document says that ``"status":"-5"`` means "Username or password is invalid". So could you please confirm about your username and password, again?

Comment: Is wrapping username and passoword within `"` a problem?

Comment: @sphoenix username and password are the string values. If they are not enclosed by the double or single quotes, those are used as variables. I think that in this case, other error occurs. Did you include ``"accept": "*/*"`` in header? If you have already done it, I'm sorry. If you have not done it, please confirm the updated my answer. In this modified script, ``JSON.stringify()`` was removed from ``JSON.stringify(payload)``. Can you try to test again? If this didn't work yet, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing json request I made a http request to send sms.

Here is the code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var username = "*****";
  var password =  "****";

  var msg = "Harry kane didn't score!!! why!!!! why on August!!! :'(";

  var phone = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

  var url = "http://clients.muthofun.com:8901/esmsgw/sendsms.jsp?user="+username+"&password="+password+"&mobiles="+phone+"&sms="+msg;

  Logger.log(url)

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

  Logger.log(response);



}
```